# heroku push error: "rake assets:precompile rake aborted!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to push my changes to Heroku with the following command: git push heroku master

When running the rake assets:precompile, I get the following error(s):

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NameError: undefined local variable or method `fkalkhalidi' for #<Pinteresting::Application:0x007f48fd2d6fc0>
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/config/environments/production.rb:80:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_deb19ff2fabe605365740a1f29b87f8b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Appreciate any help. First time learning RoR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's inside the file `config/environments/production.rb` at line 80?

Search your code, specifically in the `production.rb` file. It's likely there is a `fkalkhalidi` string somewhere that is causing the error.

Comment: Line 80 has this: 

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: fkalkhalidi-pinteresting.herokuapp.com}

It's pointing to my heroku custom domain.

The strange thing I was able to push to heroku before. But after I installed and configured devise, this was no longer the case.

Comment: it seems i didn't add http:// to the front of that. I just realized my own mistake posting that. Thanks for the help Simone!